# Utilize WP-CLI from inside WordPress, not SSH

Tags: php, plugin-development, debug, wp-cli

I'm looking for a way to test out some [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org) commands but from the [Debug Bar Console](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar-console/) where I normally test **PHP**. For cases when I don't want to switch windows to **SSH**, this might be a way to reuse/develop effective **CLI** methods outside of the **CLI**.

I've seen [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) but it only shows me what appears to be the last line of the command.

```
echo exec('ls -la'); // -rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 18108 Jan 20 21:57 widgets.php
```

Has anyone tried to string a more complex set of commands together and in a way that is more human-readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) might still work with the right variables.

```
$last_line = exec( $command, &$output, &$return_var )
```

The second parameter captures all the return data while the return from the function captures the last line.

---

- [`string exec( string $command, array &$output, int &$return_var )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) is for calling a system command, and perhaps dealing with the output yourself.
- [`string shell_exec( string $cmd )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string.
- [`string system( string $command, int &$return_var )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) is for executing a system command and immediately displaying the output - presumably text.
- [`passthru( string $command, int &$return_var )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) is for executing a system command which you wish the raw return from - presumably something binary.

---

```
$commands = array(
    'wp --version',
    'whoami',
    'pwd',
    'ls -la',
    'wp theme list',
    'wp plugin list',
);

echo '<pre>'.PHP_EOL;
foreach ($commands as $command ) { 

    // run command
    exec($command, $retval);

    // convert output array to text
    echo implode(PHP_EOL, $retval) . PHP_EOL;

    // clear the var for the next command
    unset($retval);
}
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: What should I do with it? sustitute the arrays list by the CLI install commands?

Answer (score 1):

WP-CLI is not different from any other server side utilities in that you need to be able to have the permission to run them out of a webserver enviroment using `exec`, `spawn` or friends. For obvious reasons all those kinds of PHP APIs are going to be blocked on most servers and therefor it is unlikely that a server you do not manage (don't have SSH access is an indication) will let you run WP-CLI out of wordpress.

Comment: Sorry, was thinking blue sky there for a minute with the whole non-SSH access. The real reason is that I'm lazy and don't want to manage a bunch of windows if I can quickly pull some data from the console. Looks like it's working now and giving me all the info I was hoping for.

Comment: I forgot I have a terminal window in PHPStorm... so... I guess this was more a thought exercise.