# WP-CLI methods for get_current_blog_id, get_blog_details or $wpdb->prefix

Tags: multisite, database, migration, wp-config, wp-cli

I'm looking for some extra information about an mu [site](http://wp-cli.org/commands/site/list/) (`--url`) when attempting to [export](http://wp-cli.org/commands/db/export/) from a remote server to my local testing environment.

One requirement for [migration](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/235879/whats-the-fastest-way-least-amount-of-steps-to-locally-import-a-remote-databa) is the existing [`blog_id`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_blog_id) and database [`prefix`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Class_Variables). Using those I can do a search/replace on the `exported.sql` for `<wp-prefix>_<blog_id>_` to slot it into the correct db table on [import](http://wp-cli.org/commands/db/import/).

**Search and Replace**

`printf "%s" "$(sed "s/$blog_id_old/$blog_id_new/g" <<< "$(gunzip < $input)")" > $output;`

Is there a [better way](https://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blog_details) to get the `blog_id` here? And can I get more information like the table `prefix` without running [`eval`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/eval/)?

**Blog ID**

`blog_id=$(wp eval --url=http://domain.com/site-name/ 'echo get_current_blog_id();');`

**DB Prefix**

`prefix=$(wp eval --url=http://domain.com/site-name/ 'global $wpdb; echo $wpdb->prefix;')`

Thanks.

Comment: From a quick look there doesn't seem to be. Both of these depend on global vars, which have no dedicated command to access (I think) like options do.

Comment: Do you think there should be a command for site or DB information?

Comment: That is probably better aimed at WP CLI developers. :)

Comment: It seems like this is the only good place to talk about it now. http://wp-cli.org/blog/support-policy.html hopefully some of the developers are on here. I don't mind making a PR if it doesn't feel too much like a loan wolf request.

Comment: I am aware of the post, but hardly anything we can do _here_ if it's something WP CLI just doesn't seem to do. And its developers is whose opinion on PR would _matter_, unlike us. :) I see no harm in bringing that on issue tracker there, especially if it is something you are willing to develop and contribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [wp db prefix](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/db/prefix/) command with the --url argument to determine the prefix for that particular site. If you need to determine the urls still, maybe consider using something like the [wp site list](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/site/list/) command.